# How to navigate to the LoginView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

Hi I'm trying to navigate to the login view after **PIN** is entered.

The steps that I want to do:

1. Enter a Pin.
2. Show Login Page.

But for example the PinView is this:

```
struct ConfirmPinSheet: View {
    @State private var pinCode = ""
    @ObservedObject var createPinVM: CreatePinViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Dragger()
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            
            Text("Please **confirm** a 4-digit PIN **You will use this PIN to access your account.**")
                .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Light", size:18))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            VStack{
                TextField("Enter pin", text:$pinCode)
                Button("Confirm Pin") {
                  presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                  createPinVM.showLoginPage = true
                 }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }.padding(30)
    }
}
```

And for login page I have some LoginView()

But for **MainView** where I should decide what to show **CreateAccount** or **LoginView**

how can I provide the info from ObservedObject, into AppDelegate?

**MainView**:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var createPinVM: CreatePinViewModel
    var body: some View {
        if createPinVM.showLoginPage {
            SignIn()
        } else {
            CreateAccount()
        }
    }
}
```

And AppView:

```
struct DumbApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView(createPinVM: <#T##CreatePinViewModel#>)
        }
    }
}
```

what should I insert here in DumbApp?

How to pass that change from **PinView**?

Comment: Read about `StateObject` and `EnvironmentObject`

Comment: I actually did that with EnvironmentObject, but I created new ObservableObject class, and add that into scenedelegate with StateObject, and .environmentObject() modifier, but I am curios if it's possible to create that environmentObject inside PinView

Comment: You don't have anything called `PinView` in your code. But yes, you can create an environment object anywhere you want, but then you can only inject it *down* into the view hierarchy. Not back up.